# Spring Redis Get Values by Wildcard Keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I am using Spring Data RedisTemplate (not Repository). Everything works fine with

```
template.opsForValues().get("mykey:1")
```

But I have some more complex keys such as "myobject:**somesituation**:1" and "myobject:anothersituation:2" and so on. I need to do something like:

```
template.opsForValues().get("myobject:somesituation:*")
```

With the wildcard, I would like to get all values in the "**somesituation**", no matter what is its id.

Using redis command line, I have no problem.

Obs.: I am using reactive template, don't know(believe) if this could be the problem.
Obs2: After a research, I have just found posts about Spring Repository, get all keys, get by command line, etc. But not about my specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use:

[image]

In the red rectangle, i marked the method you should use in order to achieve your goal.

You can do something like:

```
Set<String> keys = template.keys("myobject:somesituation:*")
```

and then query your set of keys.

Hope this helps.

Comment: KEYS is a blocking command and generally discouraged to use against production systems. https://redis.io/commands/keys

Answer (score 4):

Would a redis hash better model your data?
https://redis.io/topics/data-types

instead of top level keys

```
myobject:somesituation:1
myobject:somesituation:2
myobject:somesituation:3
```

at the top level you have one key

```
myobject:somesituation
```

and the value itself has key/value pairs

```
Object value = template.opsForHash().get("myobject:somesituation", "1");
```

or, to get all the values

```
Map<Object,Object> map = template.opsForHash().entries("myobject:somesituation");
value = map.get("1");
```

Avoid using redis KEYS command, as it blocks all redis clients while it executes.  SCAN is not much better, if you have allot of keys it can require hundreds of roundtrips to redis to scan the whole keyspace.